# Change One Word Color In TextBox Using C#

Tags: c#, colors, textbox

I have a textbox called `txtMessages` and I want to change The text color in That TextBox, but not the whole text For example :

> KrAToS : Hi I Have A Problem

I Want the Part KrAToS Which is (`this.client.NetworkName`) Colored in Red But The Rest Of the Text Remain Black.

Here is my code : Hope That Anyone Will Help Thanks in Advance

```
    private void SendMessage()
    {
        if ( this.client.Connected && this.txtNewMessage.Text.Trim() != "" )
        {
            this.client.SendCommand(new Proshot.CommandClient.Command(Proshot.CommandClient.CommandType.Message , IPAddress.Broadcast , this.txtNewMessage.Text));
            this.txtMessages.Text += this.client.NetworkName;
            this.txtMessages.Text += " : " + this.txtNewMessage.Text.Trim() + Environment.NewLine;
            this.txtNewMessage.Text = "";
            this.txtNewMessage.Focus();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use `RichTextBox` instead.

Comment: Are you using `winforms` or `wpf`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to match the keywords and color it as you want:

```
Dictionary<string,Color> dict = new Dictionary<string,Color>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
dict.Add(client.NetworkName,Color.Red);
//you can add more pairs
//build the pattern whenever you finish adding more entries to your dict    
string pattern = string.Format("(?i)({0})",string.Join("|",dict.Select(el=>el.Key).ToArray()));
[DllImport("user32")]
private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
//TextChanged event handler for your richTextBox1
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        int currentIndex = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
        int currentSelectionLength = richTextBox1.SelectionLength;
        //BeginUpdate
        SendMessage(richTextBox1.Handle, 0xb, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        var matches = Regex.Matches(richTextBox1.Text, pattern);
        richTextBox1.SelectAll();
        richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
        foreach (Match m in matches)
        {
            richTextBox1.SelectionStart = m.Index;
            richTextBox1.SelectionLength = m.Length;
            richTextBox1.SelectionColor = dict[m.Value];
        }
        richTextBox1.SelectionStart = currentIndex;
        richTextBox1.SelectionLength = currentSelectionLength;
        //EndUpdate
        SendMessage(richTextBox1.Handle, 0xb, new IntPtr(1), IntPtr.Zero);            
        richTextBox1.Invalidate();
}
```

Comment: @KrAToSThe.Best **How didn't it work**? Do you know how to register an event handler in C#? I've tested this code before posting it here (I'm not so professional to write it right here without testing first).